# Parse oneof typefields in golang Protoc plugin

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am building a protoc compiler plugin and I am stuck reading the contents of oneof fields.
I have a variable of type descriptorpb.OneofDescriptorProto but I don't know how to get a list of the contained messages.
Does someone know how to access this information?

Here is part of the code I use.

1. I iterate through the list of protofiles that are provided through stdin.
2. In every protofile I iterate the contained messages
3. In this case I iterate oneof fields in messages

At that point I do not get the fields contained in oneof fields.

```golang
var req pluginpb.CodeGeneratorRequest
proto.Unmarshal(data, &req)
protoFiles := req.ProtoFile

for _, protoFile := range protoFiles {
    for _, message := range protoFile.MessageType {
        for _, oneof := range message.OneofDecl {
            log.Println(*oneof.Name)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, sorry. I added more detail and a code example.